# Xcode freezing on VMware

Tags: xcode, vmware

I'm not sure if this is the place to post this but I'm using Xcode on my laptop running on VMware and every time I try to run my app on a device and try to connect over a network within the app, the app freezes. When I try to stop the run the app closes but Xcode freezes and I have to force quit it. Same thing happens if I try to stop the app without starting network connection. This does not happen on my Hackintosh. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "run my app on a device and try to connect over a network"? Running the app from Xcode over a network connection (instead of USB), or making a network connection from within the app?

Comment: I'm making a network connection from within the app and the app freezes. I should've been more clear.

Comment: Is this a minimal app you can post the source code of and show where it freezes? If not, I'd try making a minimal app that just makes an HTTP request or something to ensure it's not related to your code.

Comment: I've tried tcp and bluetooth connection to no avail. The minute I hit the connect button it freezes. The becomes unresponsive and there is no error from the log. It runs fine when I run it from my PC so I'm sure it's not my app.

Comment: When I plugged my laptop into the wall everything works, the app runs and Xcode no longer freezes. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be that the app is hitting a breakpoint or exception somewhere, causing the Xcode debugger to trigger. The debugger often hogs CPU to the point of almost freezing my PC (well, it didn't until Swift was added), and maybe your laptop is in some power saving CPU downclock when it's not plugged in, so it hangs for a while. That's my best guess, but it's still a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find a solution to this problem but I have found out that this issue goes away when the laptop is plugged into the wall. If the laptop is unplugged I have to wait a while (a minute) for the connection to establish.